# I got unwanted digits in echo

Tags: php, geoip, maxmind

I have used this code

```
$ip =  change_ipv4_ipv6($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$giasn = geoip_open("GeoIPASNumv6.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
$asn = geoip_name_by_addr_v6($giasn, $ip);
geoip_close($giasn);
```

after this code i echo record like this

```
echo 'Shell';
```

It gives result like this

> 1111111111111111111Shell

When i remove geopip code then it shows result like below

> Shell

I want to get ride of these Ones. Any advice

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that somewhere in one of those functions a 1 is being printed.

Search for print/echo in the geoip functions, it's a stab in the dark, but I'd like to guess that it is echoing a boolean.

When you said `"When i remove geopip code then it shows result like belo"w`

This should give you a clue that the echo is coming from the **geoip code**, try commenting out the functions one by one to figure out which function is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

I tested this with the latest version of the [GeoIP from GitHub](https://github.com/maxmind/geoip-api-php) and I could not reproduce it. I would recommend upgrading your version of the library.

Answer (score 0):

These ones certainly get echoed somewhere else in the code. Try to include an unmodified copy of the geoip library, or try to find the exact place in your code where they get echoed.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress output from geoip function by using `ob_start()` and `ob_end_clean()`:

```
ob_start();
$ip =  change_ipv4_ipv6($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
$giasn = geoip_open("GeoIPASNumv6.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
$asn = geoip_name_by_addr_v6($giasn, $ip);
geoip_close($giasn);
ob_end_clean();

echo 'Shell';
```

Answer (score 0):

I got issue. Putting here might help some one else come on this post

I have a function called in my code to convert ip class. here that was

```
change_ipv4_ipv6($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

in this function i was echoing answer. I replace all echo with return. now 1111111 disappear. thanks for your useful answers